# Python HTTPServer CORS

Tags: python, cors

I am trying to add in headers to allow CORS functionality to an `HTTPServer`. Various digging brought me to this solution.

I know that the headers are getting set (or at least the buffer is) with the output below. However I am still not able to fetch to another FQDN.

```py
import json
import os
import time
import traceback

from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from threading import Thread


url_host = '127.0.0.1'
url_port = 9000
url_page = 'index.html'
fqdn = f'http://{url_host}:{url_port}'
full_url = f'{fqdn}/{url_page}'


def main():
    try:
        server, thread = serve_webpage()    
    except Exception as e:
        server.shutdown()
        thread.join()
        input("Error:\n\n" + "".join(traceback.format_exception(e)))


class CORSRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
        self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate')
        print("\t\n" + "\t\n".join([f"'{header}'" for header in self._headers_buffer]))
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)


def serve_webpage():

    print(f'Serving {fqdn}')

    try:
        http_server = HTTPServer((url_host, url_port), CORSRequestHandler)
        http_thread = Thread(target=http_server.serve_forever)
        http_thread.start()

        
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f'Displaying {full_url}')
        os.system(f'start {full_url}')
        
        # server.shutdown()
        # thread.join()

        return(http_server, http_thread)

    except PermissionError as e:
        print("".join(traceback.format_exception(e)))
        print(f"Couldn't bind on port {url_port}, permission issue")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
Serving http://127.0.0.1:9000
Displaying http://127.0.0.1:9000/index.html
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2023 15:47:06] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -

'b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n''
'b'Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.11.5\r\n''
'b'Date: Thu, 14 Sep 2023 20:47:06 GMT\r\n''
'b'Content-type: text/html\r\n''
'b'Content-Length: 1655\r\n''
'b'Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Sep 2023 19:44:11 GMT\r\n''
'b'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n''
'b'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *\r\n''
'b'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *\r\n''
'b'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate\r\n''
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2023 15:47:06] "GET /js/setup-map.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -

'b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n''
'b'Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.11.5\r\n''
'b'Date: Thu, 14 Sep 2023 20:47:06 GMT\r\n''
'b'Content-type: application/javascript\r\n''
'b'Content-Length: 12005\r\n''
'b'Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Sep 2023 20:44:12 GMT\r\n''
'b'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n''
'b'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *\r\n''
'b'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *\r\n''
'b'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate\r\n''
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2023 15:47:06] "GET /json/route_coordinates.json HTTP/1.1" 200 -

'b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n''
'b'Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.11.5\r\n''
'b'Date: Thu, 14 Sep 2023 20:47:06 GMT\r\n''
'b'Content-type: application/json\r\n''
'b'Content-Length: 72009\r\n''
'b'Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Sep 2023 16:29:25 GMT\r\n''
'b'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n''
'b'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *\r\n''
'b'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *\r\n''
'b'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate\r\n''
```

```js
var tokenServiceUrl = "https://samples.azuremaps.com/api/GetAzureMapsToken";
Console.Log("Trying to fetch from " + tokenServiceUrl);
fetch(tokenServiceUrl).then(r => r.text()).then(token => resolve(token));
```

`Access to fetch at 'https://samples.azuremaps.com/api/GetAzureMapsToken' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: Did you try running your own server as the external API to validate the issue is not the API servers CORS policy?